# Obtaining the value from Flux<> in Polymer based client app

Tags: java, kotlin, polymer-2.x, project-reactor

I have created a simple Spring boot 2.0 based application which has a controller that produces `MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE`. Here is the code for controller method:

```
@GetMapping(path = arrayOf("/all"), produces = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE))
fun getAll(): Flux<Person> = registry.getAllPersons()
            .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1L))
```

When this REST API is called directly from the browser or Postman, it produces expected result ie. each `Person` object is shown as they are produced. I have crated a sample client application using `Polymer 2.0` which uses `iron-ajax` to call above api and display in a tabular format using following code:

```
<iron-ajax 
    auto 
    url="http://localhost:9090/api/person/all" 
    handle-as="json" 
    last-response="{{persons}}">
</iron-ajax>
```

The problem is that when this request is made, I get following error:

```
{
    "timestamp":1510828038673,
    "path":"/api/person/all",
    "message":"Response status 406 with reason \"Could not find acceptable representation\"",
    "status":406,
    "error":"Not Acceptable"
}
```

This request works if I remove `produces` from `@GetMapping` and `delayElements()` from `Flux`. My question is: How do I make it work with `Polymer` without removing `delayElements()`?

Comment: Can't give specific solutions (very little JS) knowledge. But you should look for something that can hand streams. Take look at the media type of the response.

Comment: It sounds like a content type negotiation issue only, wonder why removing the delayElements would change anything. What was the error? Have you tried setting an `Accept` header with `application/json+stream`? The json+stream specification indicates that it must be parsable like json, so iron-ajax should be able to parse it then (but if it has no streaming parser capability, then it won't have much benefit).

Comment: @SimonBaslé, I have tried doing that. You see, the value of: `APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE` is `application/stream+json`. The error response code is `406` as mentioned above in the question.

Comment: no, I meant in the GET request on the client side. The server basically advertises that it only can produce `json+stream`, while the client says "I want `json` only". But if iron-ajax can't support streaming json, there's not much to do anyway...